# A way to access camera in javascript in safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, getusermedia

Is it possible to access camera to make snapshots using safari browser(mobile and PC)?

What people use instead of getUserMedia/Stream API in safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile Safari offers no means to do that.

Desktop Safari has no native means, but you can use a browser plugin. For example, [Adobe Flash and the Camera class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d49.html).